# Can I configure Brain.js to have it output an array of numbers between 0 and 1?

Tags: javascript, brain.js

I'm training an LSTM to try to predict the next most probable keys of (a-z) after each keystroke. (and show only the 8 most probable successor keys to the user, which should result in an 8 key keyboard, like I did earlier [here](https://ashware.nl/magickeys2/) but that is without brain.js)

The network is trained with a chunk of text from which is taken all sets of two letters as input for the network. The corresponding output is the letter following the set of two.

I tried different config settings and training data models:

- Train the network with strings -> it outputs one character (which is not enough)
- Train the network with a set of weighted arrays of 27 items (one entry for each letter + space) -> it outputs a **string** of 26 zeros and a 1 - the position of the 1 corresponding to a letter. Although I trained it with an **array** as output. -> Still just one letter

When I run the network with two letters as input, it outputs one letter - as I trained it to.

Now how could build/model my training data to train it to output an array of the most probable successor letters.

Is this possible at all with brain.js?

Answer (score 0):

Your initial training data should be based from a long text, from which you can extract the probabilities of the next letter for each letter. To prepare this training set you don't need NN, just pure math. Then train the network with this values (input one char, output one array of 26 positions with different probabilities for each char) and the predicted values should match with the "style" of the text as reference.

To be a "live" example feeded with the input of the user, you should re-train your network with every key stroke. This would probably be computationally expensive.

Comment: Thanks for answering.. I know I don't need NN per se, there's a link to a working (and learning) example in my question. I just want to find out if it can be done with NN, just to learn (NN).